# How to add the Flash input parameters to the HTML5 code generated from Google Swiffy?

Tags: html

I've generated HTML5 code from Flash using Google Swiffy. Here's the Flash http://wordsmith.org/swiffy.html
and it takes input parameters:
`<EMBED src="anagram.swf?inputtext=Lemon|Melon&speed=10" ...>`
How do I add these input parameter to the HTML5 code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following code to the JavaScript right before `stage.start();`

```
stage.setFlashVars('inputtext=Lemon');
```